# No audio out with headphones

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-nexus, headphone-jack

When I plug a headphone into my Nexus' audio port, the headphones simply don't play any sounds or music. The device seems to detect them, because the built-in sound output stops working. I tried it with another headphone and it didn't work either. There is no error log output.

It really sucks, because I can't hear any music.

How can I solve it?

(Galaxy Nexus with stock Jelly Bean)

Comment: Have you ensured that the volume level is high enough? I have found that sometimes the volume level without headphones is too quiet when used with the headphones. If that's not it, then you have a hardware fault and should return the device for warranty repair/replacement.

Comment: @All Everett I turned the volume up to maximal possible value. :(

Comment: Well, if you're sure those headphones work, then it sounds like you have a faulty device.

Comment: It sounds correct but I'm not looking forward to order a new device and download all my apps again' although I still have my warranty

Comment: I keep hoping that there is an easier solution.

Comment: A co-worker had this problem with his Galaxy Nexus. He had to send it in to samsung 3 times... Turned out it was a hardware issue. He couldn't make any calls without headphones or speaker phone.

Comment: I found the Samsung Nexus S's "auto-off" detector switch to be faulty on mine.  If I merely _twist_ the headphone cable in the socket, it stops playback as if I had unplugged them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I own an OG Droid and a Droid Bionic and both phones eventually had similar audio jack problems.

On one phone I found the issue to be a wad of dust crammed in the jack which I had to fish out with a [enter your choice of small pointy tool].

It could be a result of the internal contact points being pushed back from repeated tension. This would weaken the contact with the audio cable. In your particular case I don't think this is true however.

Other things you can try:

- Pull the audio cable in and out several times wiggling it and testing it. (Ideally you'd want to test it with something that plays audio continuously so you don't have to keep hitting play)
- Getting a different and potentially better quality audio cable to test with.
- You can also try resetting to factory default which may help if the problem is software related. (As long as you have a google account synced with your phone, all your apps will be automatically re-downloaded)
- If all else fails, take it back to the phone manufacturer or your phone service provider. They should be able to fix it for a reasonable price.
- There is the option of trying to fix it yourself but that isn't recommended if you are uncomfortable working with small/delicate electronics, not to mention voiding your warranty.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I thought something was wrong. As soon as I inserted the headphone jack the sound got cut off and there was no sound coming thru the headphones. I tried pressing the volume button and found that it was turned all the way down by default. Now there is no problem

Answer (score 0):

My fix was to first play the media/music like first put a song or first open a game , when the sound is playing plug in the headphones or earphones

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar issue. Tried increasing, decreasing volume.. removed, put back headphones... nothing worked.. So.. did a restart of Samsung S7 Edge and it started working...